# Chat occasionally reassigns users to discuss.area51

Tags: bug, chat

Chat seems to reassign users to Discuss Area 51 on a regular basis. When it happens to me I notice because, having a diamond on Gaming, I lose my chat mod powers whenever that happens. It also happens to regular users, however. Another affected user was [Wipqozn](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12152/wipqozn) and [fredley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/11935/fredley); Ben [reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168225/chat-stubbornly-reassociates-accounts-to-discuss-area51#comment495458_168225) having had to fix other mods' accounts too.

This afternoon in particular this assignment seemed to be stuck ([10k only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168225/chat-stubbornly-reassociates-accounts-to-discuss-area51)), but the situation fixed itself (or somebody fixed it without reporting back).

What's going on?

Also noteworthy is that my current network flair is this:

[image]

However, my [Stack Exchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/7936/badp?tab=accounts) lists my accounts properly.

Comment: This is still happening, just fixed up CasperOne and Krazer a minute ago. Both synched to Area51 and were kicked out of the Teacher's Lounge temporarily.

Comment: @BenBrocka I always get worried and go to SO when this happens, checking to see if I still have my diamond.